# Data binding gives undefined value unexpectedly

Tags: knockout.js

My binding does not work anymore when I added the `computed` property to my viewModel. Without the `computed` property I have no problem. My code:

```
var orgData =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));             
    var viewModel = {
        myData: ko.observable(orgData) ,
        displayTag: ko.computed(function() {
            return "(" +  orgData.Tag + ")";
        }, this)
     };

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

and in html, my binding like this:

```
data-bind="text: myData.SerialNumber"
```

The value is `undefined` even thought the JSON data looks good.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your complete code, but you don't close the viewModel brackets here. This would throw an error and viewModel wouldn't get bound.

Comment: I missed one line of code. Please take a look again. Assume no problem with the java script and the viewModel is good., just focus on binding.

Comment: Is the Tag variable defined? If it isn't, adding the computed would break the code even if displayTag isn't used in the DOM.

Comment: You sould place a break point on this line(return "(" +  orgData.Tag + ")") to see what is in orgData.

Comment: the data are fine and the displayTag() works fine. the only problem is the "myData". <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null,2)"></pre> shows good data .

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a computed observable, rewrite your computed function to:

```
displayTag: ko.computed(function(){
   var data = this.myData();
   return "(" + data.Tag + ")";
}, this)
```

This way your computed gets updated if myData is updated. Currently, that wouldn't be the case.
If you are still seeing undefined in the display, then verify the `data.Tag` has a value.